# How to Create Custom cookie in popup Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cookie, popup

I create custom popup with custom cookie and when page is load my cookie have dot befor domain name.
How remove this dot?

Comment: How did you set your cookie? Can you please put the code in your question?

Comment: Cookie added by createPublicCookieMetadata() metod in observer

Answer (score 1):

I think in your `Store > Configuration  > General  > Web  > Default Cookie Settings`
added dot before domain name in Cookie Domain field.

[image]